# Get value from input type text

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript and try to do a simple thing. I want to get the value from an input text as you type. But can't figure out why it's not working

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('ok')
  let input = document.getElementById('test')
  console.log(input)
  console.log('2' + input.value)
}
```

```html
<input class="recherche_field" onkeyup="myFunction()" type="text" id="test" name="search_query" placeholder="Ici" />
```

and no matter what I write in my input my console show that :

```
ok
<input class=​"recherche_field" onkeyup=​"myFunction()​" type=​"text" id=​"test" name=​"search_query" placeholder=​"Ici">​
2
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: I know I tried a JSFiddle and worked great. But I don't find why It doesn't work then

Comment: @Satpal `<input class="recherche_field" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" type="text" id="test" name="search_query" placeholder="Ici" />` then `function myFunction(input) {
        console.log(input)
  console.log(input.value)
    }`worked great thanks

Comment: @Satpal any idea why it didn't work before ?

Comment: Do you have duplicate elements with same id. share `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id=test]').length)`

Comment: @Satpal hmm yes but that's weird because even if I'm doing `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id=fbhdsbfs]').length)` (totaly random letter) and obviously change the id if my input it gives me 2

Comment: But I was drop in a middle of a big dirty prestashop project so...

Answer (score 1):

Code-wise, what you have should work.

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log('keyup');
  const input = document.getElementById("test");
  console.log("2" + input.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" onkeyup="myFunc()" />
```

The most likely cause of your issue is having multiple inputs on the page with an id of "test". Every HTML element on the page should have a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

The code written by you seems fine.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Key Up Event Triggered')
  var input = document.getElementById('textBox')
  console.log(input)
  console.log('2' + input.value)
  console.log('Key Up Event Performed')
}
```

```html
<input id="textBox" type="text" placeholder="Insert Text" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
```